# Sorting a big multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a really big array containing the following data:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Berlin] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Joe
                                    [car_name] => Audi
                                    [car_color] => Black
                                    [sid] => 130 
                                )
                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Mark
                                    [car_name] => BMW
                                    [car_color] => Red
                                    [sid] => 135
                                )
                        )
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Lucas
                                    [car_name] => Audi
                                    [car_color] => Yellow
                                    [sid] => 168
                                )
                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Joe
                                    [car_name] => Volkswagen
                                    [car_color] => Black
                                    [sid] => 170 
                                )
                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Thomas
                                    [car_name] => Ford
                                    [car_color] => Gray
                                    [sid] => 119
                                )
                        )
                )
            [Moscow] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Matt
                                    [car_name] => Mustang
                                    [car_color] => Black
                                    [sid] => 230 
                                )
                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Suze
                                    [car_name] => Lada
                                    [car_color] => Red
                                    [sid] => 245
                                )
                        )
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Lucas
                                    [car_name] => Unknown
                                    [car_color] => Brown
                                    [sid] => 374
                                )
                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Mathew
                                    [car_name] => Volkswagen
                                    [car_color] => Blue
                                    [sid] => 589 
                                )
                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Thomas
                                    [car_name] => Ford
                                    [car_color] => Light Blue
                                    [sid] => 741
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Now I would like to sort it like this (please read the `//` lines):

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array //from min to max - eg. from 0 to 50
        (
            [Berlin] => Array //alphabetically from A to Z
                (
                    [1] => Array //from min to max eg. from 0 to 1
                        (
                        )
                 )
         )
)
```

How can I achieve this in PHP? I hope I was clear enough, feel free to ask in the comments for the additional info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would be something like this:

```
// ksort sorts the keys low to high

ksort($array[2]);

// uksort w/ natsort is a full alphanumeric sorting A-Z0-9
uksort($array[2]['Berlin'], 'natsort');

ksort($array[2]['Berlin'][1]);
```

Documentation on Array and Array Functions:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php

**Functional Example**

This example is real specific to your example; however, you could make a recursive style function if your array structure is really dynamic.

```
$BigArray = array();

//Sorting the initial array index
ksort($BigArray);

foreach($BigArray as $a)
{
    // Sorting Berlin / Moscow here..
    uksort($a, 'natsort');
    foreach($a as $b)
    {
        // Sorting the index inside the cities
        ksort($b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the `natsort($a)` line throws up a notice: `A PHP Error was encountered. Message: Array to string conversion`.

Comment: @Scott, Doh! Stupid mistake. See my edits. `natsort` works on values, however you can use `uksort` and add a comparison function.

Comment: Another warning now; `Warning: natsort() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given`.

Comment: Try this: `@uksort($a, 'natsort')`. It is a little ghetto, and there may be a better way, but that still is sorting properly. `uksort` passes the array in twice for comparison purposes, which `natsort` doesn't like. The @ before the function will suppress the error. If you dont need `natsort` a regular `ksort` will work (as said by Justin), the only difference is how sorting handles special characters. IE. ksort would stumble if you had 'A_Zebra', whereas `natsort` knows what to do.

Comment: It seems like the `uksort` still doesnt works - I do suppress the errors, but it still doesn't sort the array in the alphabetical order, what I noticed is that `ksort` is working fine in this case... but as you said, it would have some problems while dealing with the special characters handles.

Comment: Check out the documentation for uksort. There is a neat demo there on how to create your own function, and implementing natsort inplace of the example would be cheese. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The most compact way is to use a recursive function. This will also allow you to reuse it on arrays of different dimensions in other places in your code.

```
function SortArray($arr) {
    if(!is_array($InnerArray))
        return;
    foreach($arr as $InnerArray) {
        SortArray($InnerArray);
    }
    ksort($arr);
}
SortArray($array);
```